# Resume Brew Upgrade After Mac Sleep?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, homebrew, zsh

My mac has gone to sleep while in the middle of Brew Upgrade - and on waking from sleep, the last download it was in the middle of is not resuming. What should I do to resume?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with Mac Ports.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force the upgrade, like this :

```
brew upgrade --force
```